# UILocalNotification every working day / 15 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to make something and I need to know if my thinking is right with some help of you guys that have more experience with UILocalNotifications and stuff.

So I want to send a Local Notification to the user each working day **(Monday - Friday / 8:00 - 16:00)** and between those working hours notify the user **every 15 minutes**.

There's a limit of 64 Local Notifications if I understand that I can store inside the system. But for 1 day I would need like 32 notifications to setup (8 Hours working * 4 notifications each hour). So I could only setup 1 - 2 days that the user would receive notifications.

So how could I manage the other 3 days from Wednesday - Friday? How would you guys do this?

Should i need to store all NSDates in an Array, and always check on the current day and stuff then setup the LocalNotification when opening the app?

With kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Apples Push Notification if the app is not opened often enough to post the new LocalNotifications and you have an internet connection all the time.
If you want to post the LocalNotifications at every start of the app, I would suggest you to generate the notifications (after deleting the old ones: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`), because then you does not need to save them anywhere.